# Trigonometry/algebra Additional Maths IGCSE Question

Tags: trigonometry

Hi I have been struggling with this question for a while, any help gratefully received:

Show that $$2 \cos x \cot x + 1 = \cot x + 2 \cos x $$ can be written in the form $$(a \cos x - b)(\cos x - \sin x) = 0,$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants to be found.

Comment: I would expand the second equation first. You will notice it also in terms of cosine and sine only. So rewrite your first equation in terms of cosine and sine.

Answer (score 0):

From 
$$ 2\cos x \cot x + 1 = \cot x + 2 \cos x $$
we obtain
$$
2\cos x \cot x + 1 - \cot x - 2 \cos x = 0,
$$
or
$$
2 \cos x \frac{\cos x}{ \sin x} + 1 - \frac{ \cos x}{ \sin x } - 2 \cos x = 0 
$$
or
$$
\frac{ 2 \cos^2 x + \sin x - \cos x - 2 \cos x \sin x}{ \sin x} = 0,
$$
and hence 
$$
2 \cos^2 x + \sin x - \cos x - 2 \cos x \sin x = 0
$$
or
$$
\cos x (2 \cos x - 1) - \sin x ( 2 \cos x - 1) = 0
$$
or 
$$
( \cos x - \sin x)(2 \cos x - 1) = 0
$$
or
$$
(2 \cos x - 1)( \cos x - \sin x) = 0,
$$
which is your desired relation with $a = 2$ and $b = 1$.